# Use data URI image as material

Tags: image, three.js, data-uri

Here is what I did, export the data URI and append it to the DOM for verification. But once I add it as a texture to a geometry, it can not be rendered. [codepen link](http://codepen.io/angelathewebdev/pen/ZbNeQZ?editors=101)

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = DATA_URI;
document.body.appendChild(image); //the image is displayed properly

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: new THREE.Texture(image)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with you texture. It is the camera that has the problem. Place it at:

```
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 100 );
```

[**Updated:**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epavQp?editors=101)  pen

Comment: A couple of questions, why is the text blurred and why does it have a black background whereas the image itself does not?

Comment: those are two totally different questions but for the first one it is because you are taking text, converting it to pixels and then stretching those pixels to fit your geometry.